# Cannot parse Google Play app ratings data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encoding, character-encoding

Google Play ecosystem allows ratings data to be accessible from bucket, i.e. cloud storage.
While I can successfully download CSV from Play developer's console and process it, the file is in utf-16 encoding. Here are the first 180 bytes:

```
'255,254,80,0,97,0,99,0,107,0,97,0,103,0,101,0,32,0,78,0,97,0,109,0,101,0,44,0,65,0,112,0,112,0,32,0,86,0,101,0,114,0,115,0,105,0,111,0,110,0,32,0,67,0,111,0,100,0,101,0,44,0,82,0,101,0,118,0,105,0,101,0,119,0,101,0,114,0,32,0,76,0,97,0,110,0,103,0,117,0,97,0,103,0,101,0,44,0,68,0,101,0,118,0,105,0,99,0,101,0,44,0,82,0,101,0,118,0,105,0,101,0,119,0,32,0,83,0,117,0,98,0,109,0,105,0,116,0,32,0,68,0,97,0,116,0,101,0,32,0,97,0,110,0,100,0,32,0,84,0,105,0,109,0,101,0,44,0,82,0,101,0,118,0,105,0,101,0,119,0'
```

or decoded:

```
u'Package Name,App Version Code,Reviewer Language,Device,Review Submit Date and Time,Review Submit Millis Since Epoch,Review Last Update Date and Time,Review Last Update Millis Since'
```

However, when I try to access ratings via cloud storage:

```
try:
    stats = cloudstorage.listbucket(folder_path)
except Exception as e:
    raise
files = [stat for stat in stats]
newest = max(files, key=lambda f: f.st_ctime)
newest_ratings_file = cloudstorage.open(newest.filename)
s = newest_ratings_file.read()
newest_ratings_file.close()
```

, I receive next sequence of bytes (first 180 here):

```
31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,228,189,201,147,44,219,150,222,181,75,74,53,85,42,149,132,74,133,138,82,53,231,189,42,189,71,137,155,85,209,55,247,221,115,239,203,38,154,236,251,150,65,146,125,223,247,73,47,76,48,96,0,162,4,234,104,198,48,131,17,19,16,102,96,134,193,95,112,7,175,94,25,67,13,48,195,140,25,3,224,251,126,219,35,79,158,200,136,188,55,162,210,12,51,220,210,118,100,132,135,251,246,237,238,43,214,222,107,173,111,125,235,255,249,191,103,195,102,216,14,199,122,221,15,187,225,67,152,214,187,83,189,251,34,12,133,11,253,125,8,203,250,116,21,174,195,97,56,15,103,250,60,162,255,59,236,49,175,215,59,109,223,13,247,236,243,33,76,234,232
```

Which doesn't look like any known encoding to me.
Trying to decode using 'utf-8', 'utf-16', 'utf-16-be', 'utf-16-le' leads to decoding errors like:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position 170-171: illegal encoding
```

CharDetect (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) didn't help as well :(

I have not much idea where to move next. Guys/Girls, any suggestions how to resolve this ?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried forcing content_type="binary/octet-stream" when opening the file?

Comment: This article seems to have a script to do what you need, might be worth reading[1]. You can also try this site to see the UTF[2]. The docs say it should be UTF-16.

[1] http://artymiak.com/how-i-analyze-my-google-play-android-app-install-stats-with-python/
[2] http://2cyr.com/decode/

Comment: @JulianGo content_type can only be specified for writing mode.

Comment: @Ryan [1] - >>Download the ZIP file. The articles describes processing downloaded manually files. I'm trying to implement fully automated solution.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure how to insert binary data into the [2]. Tried saving to string and pasting - didn't help

Comment: Can you access the file in Cloud Storage browser? What value does it say for Content-type and Content-Encoding ?

Comment: @JulianGo ok, it looks like I need to unzip it first. I used gsutil ls -L and got:
 Content-Encoding:  gzip
 Content-Length:  4117
 Content-Type:  text/csv; charset=utf-16le

Comment: @JulianGo Thank you very much. Unzipping and decoding worked! Thank you very much. If you move your comment to be an answer, I can vote for and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the file Content-Type and Content-Encoding using [Cloud Storage browser](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/storage/browser) or `gsutil ls -L <file>` to get some clue on how to decode it.

In this case(`Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Type:text/csv; charset=utf-16le`), the file needs to be unzipped then decoded.